# How can I find the position of the first value of every matrixrow that equals or is greater than a pre-defined value?

Tags: r, matrix, position

I have a datamatrix where column 1 consists of plot numbers and the rest of the columns consists of pressure data, with every column corresponding to an certain soil depth (from 1 to 80).

I want to find the position (the columnnumber/columnname) of the first value in each row that exceeds a pre-determined value (f.e. 3) and store this in a vector.

The dataframe looks something like this:

| plot | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | .... | 80 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| plot 1 | 0.5 | 1.5 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 2 | 3.2 | 3.6 | ... | 4 |
| plot 2 | 0.8 | 1.4 | 1.8 | 2 | 2.6 | 2.9 | 3.2 | ... | 2.8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried splitting the matrix into vectors and using detect_index() and position(), but I cannot seem to get it right.

Ideally I would get something like this in return:

| plot | depth |
| --- | --- |
| plot 1 | 6 |
| plot 2 | 7 |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: I would convert to long format using [`tidyr::gather`] - all columns apart the plot one (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) and then [`dplyr::filter`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max.col` :

```
result <- data.frame(plot = df$plot, depth = max.col(df[-1] > 3, ties.method = 'first'))
result

#    plot depth
#1 plot 1     6
#2 plot 2     7
```

`df[-1]` ignores the 1st column, comparing it with `> 3` gives logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) and with `ties.method = 'first'` we ensure that the 1st `TRUE` value is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
M<-matrix(rnorm(25),nrow=5)
apply(M,1,function(x) which(x>0))
```

Running this code results in this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 4

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 5

[[3]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 1 3 4 5
```

First I create a random 5x5 matrix, and then I check which places of each row are over a certain value (in this case >0).